# Difference between OData, REST and client object model

Tags: csom

I am new to SharePoint, and confused about all of these terminologies, what are the differences between these 3? when do we use each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both CSOM and REST are based on the same web service `Client.svc` in SharePoint 2013.

### CSOM

The following list provides guidance on when to use CSOM endpoints:

- Create a .NET application that performs CRUD operations on
  SharePoint data
- Create an HTML/JavaScript application that performs CRUD operations
  on SharePoint data
- Create an app for Office that works with SharePoint
- Create an ASP.NET web application that performs CRUD operations on
  SharePoint data or external data that is surfaced in SharePoint by a
  BCS external content type

### REST/OData endpoints

OData defines an abstract data model and a protocol that let any client access information exposed by SharePoint. The OData protocol is based on REST which define how HTTP verbs are used.

SharePoint REST service architecture
[image]

The following list provides guidance on when to use REST/OData endpoints:

- Create an iOS or Android app that performs CRUD operations on
  SharePoint data
- Create a LAMP web application that performs CRUD operations on
  SharePoint data or external data that is surfaced in SharePoint by a
  BCS external content type

### References

- [Choose the right API set in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060.aspx)
- [SharePoint 2013 .NET Server, CSOM, JSOM, and REST API index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn268594.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You will find many references for the basic definitions of REST and OData. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458407/difference-between-odata-and-rest-web-services) provides a good overview.

Now in a SharePoint Context:

SharePoint has a service exposed called **client.svc** which is the endpoint for all client related operations.

The **SharePoint 2013 REST API** (_api) is a REST API which has operations exposed which can read and modify SharePoint data. You can call this like any other REST API e.g. through the jQuery.ajax function.

The **Client Object Model** is also a wrapper which internally calls client.svc. The difference here is that it provides a set of typed classes to work with.

Comment: Adding to the above to answer "when do we use each one"?   You would use these when you had a need to integrate an external system/process with SharePoint.  The toolsets you are using to develop the integrations would help drive which option you would choose.  For example, if I am writing a desktop application in C#, I would choose the 'Client Object Model' as it provides strongly typed objects for my SharePoint site.  If I was using a non-C# platform that could consume RESTful web services, I would use the REST API.  If my platform supported OData feeds, I would use the OData services.

Comment: So does the REST API call client.svc? Where's the use of OData here?